Error when running code for a lambda calculus program
I am creating a lambda calculus programming language written in python that should evaluate a lambda expression and reduce it by the three types of reductions which are Alpha. Beta, and Eta. For the alpha reduction, I want to find out how can I make it replace a lambda variable. For #x.x should be changed to #j.j.The code runs and does the beta reduction but for the alpha reduction it outputs what was entered.
     # Parsing rules

     # expr: An expression can be a variable, a function application, or a lambda abstraction
     def p_expr_var(p):
          'expr : VAR'
          p[0] = Var(p[1])  # Create a Var node

     def p_expr_func_arg(p):
          'expr : func arg'
          p[0] = Application(p[1], p[2])  # Create an Application node

     def p_expr_lambda(p):
          'expr : HASH VAR DOT expr'
          p[0] = Lambda(p[2], p[4])  # Create a Lambda node

     # func: A function can be a variable, a lambda abstraction within parentheses, or a function application
     def p_func_var(p):
          'func : VAR'
          p[0] = Var(p[1])  # Create a Var node

     def p_func_lambda(p):
          'func : LPAREN HASH VAR DOT expr RPAREN'
          p[0] = Lambda(p[3], p[5])  # Create a Lambda node

     def p_func_application(p):
          'func : func arg'
          p[0] = Application(p[1], p[2])  # Create an Application node

     # arg: An argument can be a variable, a lambda abstraction within parentheses, or a function application within parentheses
     def p_arg_var(p):
          'arg : VAR'
          p[0] = Var(p[1])  # Create a Var node

     def p_arg_lambda(p):
          'arg : LPAREN HASH VAR DOT expr RPAREN'
          p[0] = Lambda(p[3], p[5])  # Create a Lambda node

     def p_arg_application(p):
          'arg : LPAREN func arg RPAREN'
          p[0] = Application(p[2], p[3])  # Create an Application node

     def p_error(p):
          print("Syntax error at '%s'" % p.value if p else "Syntax error at EOF")  # Handle syntax error

     # Build the parser
     parser = yacc.yacc()

     # Semantic analysis: alpha conversion to avoid variable capture
     def alpha_conversion(expr, old_var, new_var):
          """
          Performs alpha conversion to avoid variable capture.

          Args:
               expr (Expr): The expression to perform alpha conversion on.
               old_var (str): The old variable to replace.
               new_var (str): The new variable to replace with.

          Returns:
               Expr: The converted expression.
          """
          if isinstance(expr, Var):
               # If the variable matches the old variable, replace it with the new variable
               if expr.name == old_var:
                    #replacement_var = 'j'
                    #new_var = replacement_var
                    return Var(new_var)
               else:
                    return expr
          elif isinstance(expr, Lambda):
               # If the lambda variable matches the old variable, replace it with the new variable in the lambda body
               if expr.var == old_var:
                    return Lambda(new_var, alpha_conversion(expr.body, old_var, new_var))
               else:
                    # Otherwise, recursively perform alpha conversion on the lambda body
                    return Lambda(expr.var, alpha_conversion(expr.body, old_var, new_var))
          elif isinstance(expr, Application):
               # Recursively perform alpha conversion on the function and argument parts of the application
               return Application(alpha_conversion(expr.func, old_var, new_var),
                              alpha_conversion(expr.arg, old_var, new_var))

     # Beta reduction
     def beta_reduction(expr):
          if isinstance(expr, Application):
               if isinstance(expr.func, Lambda):
                    return True, substitute(expr.func.body, expr.func.var, expr.arg)  # Apply beta reduction
               else:
                    reduced, new_func = beta_reduction(expr.func)
                    if reduced:
                         return True, Application(new_func, expr.arg)  # Reduce function part
                    else:
                         reduced, new_arg = beta_reduction(expr.arg)
                         if reduced:
                         return True, Application(expr.func, new_arg)  # Reduce argument part
          return False, expr

     # Substitute variable with value in an expression
     def substitute(expr, var, value):
          if isinstance(expr, Var):
               if expr.name == var:
                    return value  # Replace variable with value
               else:
                    return expr
          elif isinstance(expr, Lambda):
               if expr.var == var:
                    return expr
               else:
                    return Lambda(expr.var, substitute(expr.body, var, value))  # Substitute in lambda body
          elif isinstance(expr, Application):
               return Application(substitute(expr.func, var, value), substitute(expr.arg, var, value))  # Substitute in application

     # Eta reduction
     def eta_reduction(expr):
          if isinstance(expr, Lambda):
               if isinstance(expr.body, Application):
                    if isinstance(expr.body.arg, Var):
                         if expr.var == expr.body.arg.name and expr.var not in free_vars(expr.body.func):
                         return True, expr.body.func  # Apply eta reduction
          return False, expr

     # Find free variables in an expression
     def free_vars(expr):
          if isinstance(expr, Var):
               return {expr.name}  # Return variable as a set
          elif isinstance(expr, Lambda):
               return free_vars(expr.body) - {expr.var}  # Remove bound variable
          elif isinstance(expr, Application):
               return free_vars(expr.func) | free_vars(expr.arg)  # Union of free variables

     # Reduce expression to normal form
     def reduce_expression(expr):
          """
          Reduce an expression to normal form using beta reduction and eta reduction.

          Args:
               expr (Expression): The expression to reduce.

          Returns:
               Expression: The reduced expression.
          """
          # Repeat beta and eta reduction until the expression cannot be reduced further
          while True:
               # Perform beta reduction
               reduced, new_expr = beta_reduction(expr)
               if reduced:
                    # Display beta reduction
                    print("Beta reduction:", expr, "=>", new_expr)
                    expr = new_expr
                    continue

               # Perform eta reduction
               reduced, new_expr = eta_reduction(expr)
               if reduced:
                    # Display eta reduction
                    print("Eta reduction:", expr, "=>", new_expr)
                    expr = new_expr
                    continue

               # Exit the loop if the expression cannot be reduced further
               break

          # Return the reduced expression
          return expr

     # Main function to display results
     def main():
          while True:
               try:
                    s = input('lambda > ')
               except EOFError:
                    break
               if not s:
                    continue
               result = parser.parse(s)
               print("Parsed expression:", result)
               print("Reduced expression:", reduce_expression(result))

     # Run main function
     if __name__ == "__main__":
          main()

